# Many to Many Relationship in MVC 5 EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6, viewmodel

Im using MVC 5 and EF 6.

There are 3 tables in my code: "Leads", "Phones", "LeadStatus" and a junction table "LeadPhones".
I want to show following properties in Index View:

```
Leads.FullName
LeadStatus.Status
Phones.PhoneID
```

How should I configure the LeadController?

```
public partial class Leads
{
    public Leads()
    {
        this.LeadPhones = new HashSet<LeadPhones>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return NamePrefix + " " + FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
    public int LeadStatusID { get; set; } 

    public virtual LeadStatus LeadStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LeadPhones> LeadPhones { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Phones
{
    public Phones()
    {
        this.AccountPhones = new HashSet<AccountPhones>();
        this.ContactPhones = new HashSet<ContactPhones>();
        this.EmployeePhones = new HashSet<EmployeePhones>();
        this.LeadPhones = new HashSet<LeadPhones>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PhoneID { get; set; }           
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LeadPhones> LeadPhones { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class LeadPhones
{
    [Key]
    public int LeadPhoneID { get; set; }
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public int PhoneID { get; set; }

    public virtual Leads Leads { get; set; }
    public virtual Phones Phones { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class LeadStatus
{
    public LeadStatus()
    {
        this.Leads = new HashSet<Leads>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int LeadStatusID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Leads> Leads { get; set; }
}
```

the following does not work:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        var leads = db.Leads.Include(l => l.LeadStatus).Include(l => l.LeadPhones);                       

        return View(leads);
    }
```

The main problem is the "PhoneNo". How could I get that from a junction table?

Comment: it's only DB, that you have. What have you tried and what wents wrong?

Comment: Remove the LeadPhoneID column from the LeadPhones table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the LeadPhoneID column from the LeadPhones table -- It isn't necessary and will only cause problems for you.  Remove all references to LeadPhones in your classes.  Leads a virtual property to Phones (not LeadPhones).  LeadPhones has a virtual property to Leads (not LeadPhones).

After you do that, then you should be able to:

```
var leads = db.Leads.Include(l => l.LeadStatus).Include(l => l.Phones);

public partial class Lead
{
    public Lead()
    {
        this.Phones = new HashSet<Phone>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return NamePrefix + " " + FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
    public int LeadStatusID { get; set; } 

    public virtual LeadStatus LeadStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
} 

public partial class Phone
{
    public Phone()
    {
        this.AccountPhones = new HashSet<AccountPhones>();
        this.ContactPhones = new HashSet<ContactPhones>();
        this.EmployeePhones = new HashSet<EmployeePhones>();
        this.Leads = new HashSet<Lead>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PhoneID { get; set; }           
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Lead> Leads { get; set; }
}   
public partial class LeadStatus
{
    public LeadStatus()
    {
        this.Leads = new HashSet<Lead>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int LeadStatusID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Lead> Leads { get; set; }
}
```

I've also corrected the plurality of your classes.  Lead vs Leads.  The class describes a single lead, so it should be called Lead not Leads.  Phone vs Phones.

Comment: I tried this. 
my Index  view is like this:
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phones.PhoneNo)</th>
Now Im getting an error in the Index view: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CL_AHR_CRM.Models.Leads>' does not contain a definition for 'Phones' and no extension method 'Phones' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CL_AHR_CRM.Models.Leads>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you are using the above classes, the model should be `IEnumerable<CL_AHR_CRM.Models.Lead>`

Comment: the model is exactly like you mentioned above. What else could be the problem?

Comment: That error message should tell you what line and file is generating it, then take a look at it because `Models.Leads` isn't valid.  It should be `Models.Lead`